# What is causing this AssertionError failure for my unit test on IndexOf arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, chai

I am doing a coding challenge. There is a section of code written along with tests to test the code. I am very new to coding and am not sure where to start.

The error I am getting says, "you should be able to determine the location of an item in an array" ‣

```
AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal 2
```

I tried declaring the variable and writing a loop but I am told these are not the way to solve this. My goal is to get the test to pass.

Here is the section of code that is written:

```
exports = typeof window === 'undefined' ? global : window;

exports.arraysAnswers = {
  indexOf: function(arr, item) {

  },
```

Here is the code that is in the tests folder:

```
if ( typeof window === 'undefined' ) {
  require('../../app/arrays');
  var expect = require('chai').expect;
}

describe('arrays', function() {
  var a;

  beforeEach(function() {
    a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
  });

  it('you should be able to determine the location of an item in an array', function() {
    expect(arraysAnswers.indexOf(a, 3)).to.eql(2);
    expect(arraysAnswers.indexOf(a, 5)).to.eql(-1);
  });
```

I expect the test to pass but have no idea where I should start. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something from your `indexOf` function:

```
indexOf: function(arr, item) {
  let index = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === item) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

Like the native `indexOf` function in JavaScript, this will return `-1` if the item is not found.